# Pyinstaller check all the hooks/packages included in bundled app

Tags: python, linux, pyinstaller

Pyinstaller version: 3.2.1
OS : Linux
Python 2.7.6

testapp.py:

```
import os
print "hello" # printing hello
os.system("gnome-terminal") #opens a new terminal.
```

Running: `pyinstaller --onefile --name=mytestapp testapp.py --log-level=DEBUG --exclude-module=Tkinter`

creates a bundle app, and runs with no issue.
the log-level creates a xref-testapp.html in build dir, which shows all the included modules. it includes other modules as well for example six, etc, which are not required by the bundled app(its okay if they are getting imported, i can get rid of them by exclude module option).

I want to create a clean list of all the modules like os, json, log, robobrowser, six, particularly which got added to app bundle from the virutalenv and the imports required by the app.
Tried couple of methods, to analyze pyz, but could not find a clear list of imports by `pyinstaller`.

Any help really appreciated.

Comment: Update: I was able to figure it myself after a long hard searching on web..
my venv had IPython installed, which was causing other modules to get compiled along with the required modules for my script.
i just had to add --exclude-module=IPython.
and was easy to sepeate the python builtins from those pip installed.